# Laravel Using Array_Replace_Recursive Only Replaces First Value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

With the data I'm attempting to pass through to a request instead of replacing the existent data in the array it is replacing the first value in the array. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
private function validParams($overrides = [])
{
    return array_replace_recursive([
        // More fields,
        'posts' => [
            1 => [
                'field1' => ...,
                'field2' => [],
                'field3' => [],
                'field4' => [],
                'users' => [1, 2],
                'field6' => ...,
            ]
        ],
    ], $overrides);
}

$this->validParams([
        'posts' => [
            1 => [
                'users' => [99],
            ]
        ],
    ]));
```

If a run the previous code it turns into this.

```
"users" => array:2 [
    0 => 99
    1 => 2
  ]
```

Instead of what is desired.

```
"users" => array:1 [
    0 => 99
  ]
```

Comment: remove the `[ ]` ( would give `array(0 => '99`) from your given replacement data at `$this->validParams()`. This will create an array, and leave the other keys. You only want to set 99, so do it without creating an array out of it ;)

Comment: Can you create an answer for this so I can see more of what you mean?

Comment: `array_replace_recursive` is not what you need, obviously.

Comment: Okay then what is it that I do need @u_mulder

Comment: I suppose you need to write a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

Edited Version:

So, i have played around a bit and tried to create a custom function to do what you need. For me it seems working. Please try it out. If I have missed something, tell me.

Basically you remove your default array out of the function, then add a variable for this base array. This allows the function to call itself and go deeper into the array.

```
// removed base
$base = ['posts' => [
    1 => [
            'field1' => '',
            'field2' => [],
            'field3' => [],
            'field4' => [],
            'users' => [1, 2],
            'field6' => '',
    ]
]];

// added base param
function validParams($base, $overrides) {
    if(is_array($overrides)) {
        // loop over override
        foreach($overrides as $key => $overrideVal) {
            // if override is an array such as base and there is a similar key in the base array, 
            // catch the base value as $baseVal. Then go one step down into base array
            if (is_array($overrideVal) && (null!==($baseVal = isset($base[$key]) ? $base[$key] : null)) && is_array($baseVal)) {
                // call self with baseval and override val
                $base[$key] = validParams($baseVal,$overrideVal);
            } else {
                // no longer an array, here we will begin to overwrite
                // loop trough known last base
                foreach ($base as $baseKey => $basVal) {
                   // if the value is given in overwrite, then overwrite it
                   if ($baseKey == $key) {
                      $base[$key] = $overrideVal;
                   } else {
                      // was not given in overwrite, remove it
                      unset($base[$baseKey]);
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $base;
}


$result = validParams($base, [
        'posts' => [
            1 => [users => [99],
            ],
        ],
    ]);

var_dump($result);
```

Sorry, I changed the code to procedural style, as it was easier to build it up.

Comment: But then it wouldn't be an array.

Comment: @user3732216 ah, just noticed, dang.

Comment: Do you know what php array function I would need.

Comment: @user3732216 I just made a big edit to my answer and tried to add a function to do what you want.